# Get some metrics with video_insights FACEBOOK API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get some metrics from a video. For example suppose to get `total_video_views` from my video.

Now I use [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/?locale=it_IT) to test my operation.

So I create this link ([video_id]/video_insights/total_video_views):

```
10155205658108477/video_insights/total_video_views
```

I click on run and I get this result :

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I try with these access token:

1. user access token and  I give it ALL permission
2. app access token
3. page access token

The video is not mine, but it belongs to another facebook page!

The result is the same. the value data is empty. Anyone can help me?

Comment: _“The video is not mine, but it belongs to another facebook page!”_ - then I don’t think you will be able to get this information via API at all. Plus, from the docs it looks like this metric is only applicable for cross-posted videos in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe  and if I want to get all the metrics of a video that is not mine how do I do it?

Comment: You simply don’t, because Facebook has decided that in this case that data is none of your bees’ swags.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for you reply!